# How to get real link from 'a' tag using simple_html_dom.php?

Tags: php, url, domdocument

I use `simple_html_dom.php` for get all values of href from web pages.
This is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url=$_GET['url']; //this is the target website address (for example, http://127.0.0.1/mysite/default.php?url=https://www.google.com)

    if($url){
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
            echo $e->href . '<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

But.. the problem is output. The output like this: `/about`, `/domains`, etc. or `//en.wikipedia.org`, `//ro.wikipedia.org`, etc. and much more.

How to convert these outputs to a standard url, for example: `http://www.example.com/about` or `https://www.example.com/page`, etc.?

Comment: It parse direct `HTML` text. So if in it written `/page` you can not get `https://www.example.com/page`. You need to add domain or protocol manually.
To check which part of URL is missing use function `parse_url`

Comment: And how cam I make this?

Comment: please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param $href string URL To Convert
 * @param $base_url string Remote server's base url. Like wikipedia.org (without http or https)
 */
function convert_url($href, $base_url = NULL){
    $parse = parse_url($href);
    $host = array_key_exists('host', $parse) ? $parse['host'] : $base_url;
    $path = array_key_exists('path', $parse) ? $parse['path'] : '/';
    $queryStr = array_key_exists('query', $parse) ? '?'.$parse['query'] : '';
    $scheme = array_key_exists('scheme', $parse) ? $parse['scheme'].'://' : 'http://';
    return $scheme.$host.$path.$queryStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

if (!empty($parsedUrl['scheme']) && !empty($parsedUrl['host'])) {
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach ($html->find('a') as $link) {
        $l = http_build_url($link->href, [
            'scheme' => $parsedUrl['scheme'],
            'host' => $parsedUrl['host']
        ]);
        echo $l . '<br>';
    }
}
```

See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-build-url.php) of function `http_build_url` for more information.

Comment: I get a fatal error.. Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_build_url()

Comment: You must enable extension `php_http.dll` (or `php_http.so` for linux).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056977/function-http-build-url#answer-14057205