# PHP regex to ignore group of characters

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple function that removes unnecessary slashes from a path or URL. I have the `preg_replace` working fine to remove two forward slashes, only I need it to ignore `://`, as this would indicate the `http://` or `https://` part of the string:

```
$string = 'http://example.com/this//that/and/the/other/file.php';

echo preg_replace("/\/{2,}/", "/", $string);

// Outputs: http:/example.com/this/that/and/the/other/file.php
```

Notice how the two forward slashes are removed in the `http://` part. How can I modify this regex to ignore two forward slashes when it is preceeded by a colon? The desired output is:

```
http://example.com/this/that/and/the/other/file.php
```

Comment: I might be old fashioned, but I don't believe regex is the cure to most things. Take a look at [`parse_url()`](php.net/manual/kln/function.parse-url.php). You have your host, and you can replace anything that must be done in the query. And I have no idea why a valid inline code comment fails at this time.

Comment: What result are you trying to get? I agree with @Xorifelse that you should be using a function like `parse_url()`

Comment: @Barmar He wants, `http://` without the double f-slash that occurs here `... this//tha ..`

Comment: I eventually figured that out. He should add that to the question to make it clear. If he uses `parse_url` it will return the pathname part as a separate string, then he can do `preg_replace('#/+#', '/', $path)`

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to explain it any simpler. I simply want to remove all double slashes except those preceded by a colon.

Comment: @JROB See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a negative lookbehind such as `/(?<!\:)\/+/`, which essentially means *"match 1 or more slashes if not preceded by a colon"*.

**Code:**

```
$string = 'http://example.com/this//that/and/the/other/file.php';

echo preg_replace("/(?<!\:)\/+/", "/", $string);
```

You can see a live example [here](https://3v4l.org/ujEc2).

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting with some caveats:

1. A url with 2 slashes in its path *is* different from a url with 1 slash in the same position. Even though on your server they might point to the same thing, it's not universal.
2. If you only care about your server, and you know it's safe to make this change, you don't really need to look for the colon, just don't make this change in the first part of the url. Note that relative urls can start with `//` and this will break if you turn that into a single slash. You might also break query parameters or fragments in this manner. Could be dangerous.
3. A URL parser that 'understands' urls is much better than a sloppy regular expression.

So in my answer I'm using a [url parser](https://packagist.org/packages/sabre/uri) and a simple `str_replace` statement.

```
 $uri = \Sabre\uri\parse($input);
 if ($uri['path']) $uri['path'] = str_replace('//', '/', $uri['path']);
 $output = \Sabre\Uri\build($uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex should be used to filter out the entire string, its fine when its something specific.

```
$string = 'http://example.com/this//that/and/the/other/file.php';
$url = parse_url($string);
$url['path'] = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', $url['path']); //The Barmar regex (essentially shorter, and thus better)

echo sprintf('%s://%s%s', $url['scheme'], $url['host'], $url['path']);
```

This should work, with a very simple regex.

You can also take a look at [`http_build_url()`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-build-url.php) which is designed to rebuild the url from parts created by [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.parse-url.php) but requires the `pecl_http` module to be enabled or choose to add an unmaintained function as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198715/4982088).