# Str_replace does not replace

Tags: php

I have variables that gets url. Then from this url I remove another url. First url removes another url but second not because it contains Russians words. How I can remove from url Russians letters:

```js
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
 page = $_GET['page'];
}
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
 $category = $_GET['category'];
}


$url = str_replace('&page='.$page, "", $url); // works
$url2 = str_replace('&category='.$category, "", $url2); // does not working

echo $url2; // i check and $url2 does not remove category, because it contains Russians words
```

Comment: Show us the return of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on each variable, please...

Comment: you can try this   str_ireplace php string function please check this in your code

Comment: @Lucas Arbex /beverages.php?lang=ru&category=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @Ravi Makwana no, it is not removing string

Comment: what is your expected output ??

Comment: @Ravi Makwana look at the top

Comment: @DenisL what is the output of `$_GET['category']` on this url?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone ups, here I have written url3 but in my code is url2

Comment: @Lucas Arbex the name of category, but in Russian

Comment: This `%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8` doesn't seem Russian to me...

Comment: @Lucas Arbex this is output of this: Безалкогольные напитки

Comment: @DenisL check if my answer below is any good, please...

Comment: Can you provide a request URI that fail to be converted and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the occurrence of the string using [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php) on `str_replace()`, like so:

```
$url2 = str_replace('&category='. urlencode($category), "", $url2);
```

Comment: not it have not helped, when I put it in a href it not changes category name but adds new and I have: &category=Безалкогольные%20напитки&category=Безалкогольные%20напитки&category=Безалкогольные%20напитки

Comment: @DenisL what do you mean with _"when I put it in a href"_. What is the output of $url2, after using `urlencode` as I've said?

Comment: output remained the same, and about href, I put it in the a tag to go to the page with category and for this I need str replace category with new

Comment: Can you show the code that you prints the a/href tag?

Comment: @Koala Yeung ok - <a href="<? echo "$url3&category=Безалкогольные напитки"; ?>">Безалкогольные напитки</a>

Comment: Where and how did you declare `$url3`?

Comment: @Koala Yeung ups, there is url2 but not url3

Comment: @DenisL: Please take a look at my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [http_build_query](http://docs.php.net/manual/uk/function.http-build-url.php) (or its [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198715/372172)) in your environment, you can write a simple function to rewrite query parameters on the fly instead of using str_replace.

For example, to rewrite the "category" parameter, you may

```php
<?php

function uri_rewrite_query($uri, $callback) {
        $parsed = parse_url($uri);
        parse_str($parsed['query'] ?? '', $query);
        $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($callback($query));
        return http_build_url($uri, $parsed);
}

function query_remove_category($query) {
  unset($query['category']);
  return $query;
}

function query_replace_category($category) {
  return function ($query) use ($category) {
    $query['category'] = $category;
    return $query;
  };
}
```

Then you can do these:

```php
<?php

$uri = '/beverages.php?lang=ru&category=some_category';

echo uri_rewrite_query($uri, 'remove_category');
// Result: /beverages.php?lang=ru

echo uri_rewrite_query($uri, query_replace_category('Безалкогольные напитки'));
// Result: /beverages.php?lang=ru&category=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8 (equivalant to "/beverages.php?lang=ru&category=Безалкогольные напитки")
```

Or if you're only interested in the query string:

```php
function uri_get_query() {
  $parsed = parse_url($uri);
  parse_str($parsed['query'] ?? '', $query);
  return $query;
}

echo '/food.php?' . http_build_query(query_remove_category($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?? ''));
echo '/food.php?' . http_build_query(query_replace_category('Безалкогольные напитки')($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?? ''));
```